# Neo4j: how does relationships concentration influence performance?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Does it influence cypher performance if a node has a large number of relationships. Lets say the node has 10 millions of relationships. Should we expect performance troubles when we touch this node in cypher?

Comment: This is a good question, I'd like to see an answer to it.   Checking the performance guide, I'm betting there are a lot of confusing factors to take into account, and that the answer won't be simple.  There are things like caching and JVM garbage collection, plus memory allocation and other things that will all have an impact.   As the number of relationships grow, I think those other factors will become more important/intense too.

Comment: Relevant link -- (although not an answer) - http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/performance-guide.html

Comment: Sure, a lot of factors influence performance. I'm wondering what contribution makes particularly the relation concentration into performance. By my experience I saw performance degradation with the rising of the relationships count. On 200K relationships it was solid. Of course there is a chance that some tuning of hardware, OS, Neo4j and query might resolve that case. But I would like to know when I should start to worry about the relationship concentration when no tuning is possible.

Comment: Starting with 2.1.x Neo4j stores dense nodes/relationships in a special way to improve the performance in such cases. More about this can be found in [this blogpost](http://neo4j.com/blog/the-neo4j-2-1-0-milestone-1-release-import-and-dense-nodes/).

Comment: @mahinko can you add anything about relationship labels or properties?   Are you trying to scale a huge number of the same type of relationships, or are they partitioned in some way?  If so, how?

Comment: @FrobberOfBits It is supposed to have a couple of labels and properties on the connected nodes. DB contains several types represented by nodes. Also it contains a lot of entities of various kind of types. So the "type" node has a lot of connections to entities nodes. I worry that with a high number of entities >10M I might have the performance problem. I was thinking that "types" might be represented by labels instead than nodes. Probably I need to do some more tests on 2.1 core.